# Rich domain in the context of packaged domain classes

Tags: java, oop, tdd, domain-driven-design

A legacy Java code-base that I'm currently working with makes use of a notorious framework. It provides me out-of-the-box domain classes in nicely packaged jars. The domain classes are nothing but bags of getters and setters.

This is preventing me from breeding a rich domain model, by extracting the procedural code from static Util classes into their rightful places, i.e. the domain classes themselves. For example, consider the logic within the following method:

```
public static boolean areFriends(User user1, User user2) {
    for (User friend : user1.getFriends()) {
        if (friend.equals(user2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This could instead be nicely expressed as `isFriendOf(User another)` in the `User` class. However, the `User` class is all locked up. By the way, the framework uses life-cycle methods to pass in the `User` objects:

```
//Life-cycle method
public void execute(FrameworkBlob frameworFattyObject) {
    ...
    User user = frameworFattyObject.getUser();
    User loggedInUser = getLoggedInUserFromSomewhere();
    bool areFriends = BadUtilClass.areFriends(user, loggedInUser);
    ...  
}
```

Keeping testability in mind, is there a way I could say something like:

```
bool areFriends = user.isFriendOf(loggedInUser);
```

Comment: I assume you do not have access to the original code in any way from your description. Is it possible for you to affect the code where the User objects are created? If so, you could subclass the User class in a new class where you add the the code you need.

Comment: Another option would be to changing the static class to a normal class and extracting an interface and make the execute method work on the interface. That would improve testability.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian I like the sub-classing idea, but unfortunately I don't have a say in how and where the User objects are created by the framework.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes the execute() method would become easier to test. But is there a way to stop areFriends() from screaming with feature envy?

Comment: @aquaraga; In C# there would be extension methods, so it would look *as if* the method is part of the User class, but it still would be simply a static method in a static class. If you can't change the User class and can't use the sub-classing approach you are - IMO - out of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with the notorious framework. I should comment first but it's too long.

Is it possible to inject something to the Life-cycle method?

For example:

```
public class AClassIDontKnow {

    private DomainModelMapper mapper;//inject this
    //Life-cycle method
    public void execute(FrameworkBlob frameworFattyObject) {
        ...
        UserDomainModel user = mapper.getUser(frameworFattyObject);
        UserDomainModel loggedInUser = getLoggedInUserFromSomewhere();
        bool areFriends = user.isFriendOf(loggedInUser);
        ...  
    }
}

public class DomainModelMapper {
    UserDomainModel getUser(FrameworkBlob frameworFattyObject) {
         User userAnemicModel = frameworFattyObject.getUser();
         //map the anemicModel to a rich domain model
         return ....;
    }
}
```

Therefore the test strategy:
1) DomainModelMapperUnitTest is placed to test the mapping.
2) UserDomainModelUnitTest covers the isFriend(user)
3) Use mock for DomainModelMapper in AClassIDontKnowUnitTest if neccessary.

Comment: I like this approach! Except for the grunt work in the mapper.

Comment: @aquaraga what's thie purpose of the life-cycle method by the way? Which layer pass the FrameworkBlob in? Could you post an example of how the execute method being invoked?